# Why does setting a state variable in an AG Grid callback in React reset the column order?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

If I move around columns in my AG Grid, i.e. drag them and change the order that they appear, and then trigger an event that sets state the column order will reset; yet, other column state (like sorting) is maintained.

I have tried making the simplest possible example which is the React example from AG Grids website, it simply shows 3 columns and 3 rows. Then, I added a single boolean state variable that is toggled in the column sort event handler.

If you run the example and drag the columns out of order, then try sorting (which toggles that state variable) the columns are reset to the original order. Then if you comment out the line that sets the state variable, go back to the site, mix up the columns, and then sort they remain the same.

The steps to create project and exact environment (as far as packages go) are:

```
npx create-react-app aggrid-test-app
cd aggrid-test-app
npm install --save ag-grid-community
npm install --save ag-grid-react
npm start
```

Here is the minimum example that you can use to recreate the problem.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useMemo } from 'react';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react'; // the AG Grid React Component

import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css'; // Core grid CSS, always needed
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css'; // Optional theme CSS

const App = () => {

  const gridRef = useRef();
  const [stateVariable, setStateVariable] = useState(true)

  const defaultColDef = {
    sortable: true
  };

  const rowData = [
    { make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
    { make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
    { make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 }
  ];

  const columnDefs = [
    { field: "make" },
    { field: "model" },
    { field: "price" }
  ];

  const onSortChanged = (event) => {
    setStateVariable(!stateVariable)
  }

  return (
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: 400, width: 600 }}>
      <AgGridReact
          ref={gridRef} 
          rowData={rowData} 
          columnDefs={columnDefs} 
          defaultColDef={defaultColDef} 
          onSortChanged={onSortChanged}
          />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: why are you using `useState` for data that is apparently not state data because you're never going to change it? Just make `rowData` and `columnDefs` normal `const` variables. Also, what is `stateVariable` for? You're updating it, but it's not being used or passed down.

Comment: It's copy/paste from AG Grid getting started: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/getting-started/. Feel free to ask them.

Comment: That's... that's your job, not ours? If you're following someone's tutorial and it doesn't work, or the code they give you does something weird that the tutorial doesn't explain, let them know so they can fix or document it?

Comment: I'll ask them too, but if this is a conceptual issue that I'm not understanding and is independent of AG Grid then who am I going to ask if not SO. 

I've taken the simplest working example, the AG Grid getting started, broke it with a simple state change, and am asking a question about why it broke. I don't think what I've done here is unreasonable.

Comment: There you go @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - I've removed the state on rowData, columnDefs, and defaultColDef and verified that the same issue is there.

The state variable models what I was actually trying to do when I discovered this issue, saving the state of the columns so that I can navigate away from a grid and when I return re-render the grid with the same state. It is of course useless in this example, but it's a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Mike is right. However, I would say this is one of the good questions I see in a couples of months (if not a year). Clear explanation with minimum reproductive example. That’s rare for a newcomer enough.